# Getting a JSON object from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am sending a JSON object from js to post.php

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'post.php',
    data:{jsonobject:json_str}
});
```

but I am not able to retrieve the result in a post.php file

```
$obj = jsonString2Obj($_POST['jsonobject']);
echo $obj->people->user;

function jsonString2Obj($str){
    return json_decode(stripcslashes($str));
}
```

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: try $obj = json_decode($_POST["jsonobject"]);

Comment: Did you share all related code for ajax ? Is it complete code ?

Comment: yes everything is there. i am converting an array to json and using JSON.stringify(jsonArr) to have a json_str object

Comment: Did you use `.done(function( data ) { ... ` ?

Comment: no, i dont know about it..

Comment: Why do you need `stripcslashes`? Do you have magic quotes turned on? **Danger!!** PHP versions which support Magic Quotes no longer get security updates! Upgrade immediately!

Comment: what if i do just like this ..$obj = json_decode($_POST['jsonobject']);


echo $obj->people->usr;

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about your `$jsonr_str`.

It's my example:

```
$json = '{"people":[{"user":"Amy"},{"user":"Lee"},{"user":"David"}]}';

// covert into object
$data = json_decode(stripcslashes($json));
echo "People[0]=" . $data->people[0]->user;

// or covert info array
$data = json_decode($json, true);

// Using print_r()
echo "<pre>" .print_r($data, true). "</pre>";
```

Comment: here is the string....[{"people":"teamA","match":"Match1","score":"32"}]

Comment: Try it `echo $data[0]->people;`. I can get `teamA`

Comment: Using `echo '<pre>' .print_r($obj, true). '</pre>'`. It's good to see ur data how to get them.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
var data = {
        people:{user:'Joe Cooper'}
    };

       $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'post.php',
    data:{jsonobject:JSON.stringify(data)}
});

<?php
$obj = jsonString2Obj($_POST['jsonobject']);


echo $obj->people->user;

function jsonString2Obj($str){
    return json_decode(stripcslashes($str));
}
```

Comment: i have already did the stringify. the problem is at the php end.. i dont know how to get this object on php side